# How to include .resource files into an assembly?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, embedded-resource, resx

I have a couple of compiled resource files (myProg.en_US.resource, myProg.de_DE.resource and so on) which are currently loaded during runtime using ResourceManager.CreateFileBasedResourceManager(). 
I want to modify that and embed the resources into the assembly. How can this be done? MSDN only speaks of .resx-files.

Comment: did you right click the resx file set Build property to Embedded Resource

Comment: The files have .resource as file extension, not .resx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the file in solution explorer, then find it's properties. there is an item called build action. You can choose the option "embedded resource"[image]

Comment: Does this make the resource files available to the ResourceManager class?

Comment: Should be, have you checked this link [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984408%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: I would love to write a complete answer but so wont let me :-) What I do is that I include the resources files as you wrote and then I call `_resourceManager = new ResourceManager("myAssemblyPrefix", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());` I guess this will do the job quite nicely. Have yet to try it... the project is quite complex and not that easily tested.